# Why does Outer sometimes return a packed array, and sometimes not?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, packed-arrays

For example

```
In[342]:= 
test3 = Flatten[Outer[Plus, Range[1000], Range[1000]], 
    1]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[342]= {0.0198735, Null}
```

returns PackedArray (examined by Developer`PackedArrayQ[test3] ), while

```
In[334]:= 
test3 = Flatten[Outer[#1 + #2 &, Range[1000], Range[1000]], 
    1]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[334]= {0.822719, Null}
```

Unpacks. And we can see the huge timing difference.

**Why different unpacking behaviour of `Outer`?**

What is more, the first `Outer` example is the fastest possible code. Even faster than Compiled to C target code.

Oddly, `Map` pure function and `Map` built-in `Total` is slow

```
In[281]:= 
test2 = (#[[1]] + #[[2]] &) /@ 
    Tuples[{Range[1000], Range[1000]}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[281]= {0.214871, Null}

In[340]:= 
test22 = Total /@ Tuples[{Range[1000], Range[1000]}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[340]= {0.176941, Null}
```

Though both of the above returns PackedArray. And they are much slower than trivial `Table`

```
In[299]:= 
test4 = Flatten[Table[i + j, {i, 1, 1000}, {j, 1, 1000}], 
    1]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[299]= {0.0530814, Null}
```

The performance is so inconsistent. I was trying to calculate something like `251001 (-1 + #1) + 501 (-1 + #2) + #3` & on `Tuples[{{1}, Range[501], Range[501]}]`, found it is a bottleneck, Tried `Map`, `Outer`, `ApplyAll`(Apply unpacks), sophisticated `Compile`, and finally found trivial `Table` is already almost the same efficiency as Compile!!

Comment: Er… personally I think this question is a little scattered, maybe you can consider divide it into 2 or 3 questions?

Comment: @xzczd Well, on the contraray, I would call "dividing it into 2 or 3" as scattered : ), and I suffered a lot from scattered questions when searching solutions on SE site. I organized them together, because all of them generate the same list, and they are what one can think of when dealing this kind of problem (I mean calculating data on a mesh)

Comment: Related: [(33624)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33624/121)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is pretty clearly a case where `Outer` is simply overloaded with an optimized definition for `Plus`.  A look at the [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) shows that there are no intermediate steps:

```
Trace[
  Outer[Plus, Range[3], Range[3]],
  TraceInternal -> True
]
```

> ```
> {{Range[3], {1, 2, 3}}, {Range[3], {1, 2, 3}}, 
>  Outer[Plus, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}], {{2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}}
> ```

By comparison observe the individual evaluation steps with a `Function`:

```
Trace[
  Outer[#1 + #2 &, Range[3], Range[3]],
  TraceInternal -> True
]
```

> ```
> {{Range[3], {1, 2, 3}}, {Range[3], {1, 2, 3}}, 
>  Outer[#1 + #2 &, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}],
>  {(#1 + #2 &)[1, 1], 1 + 1, 2},
>  {(#1 + #2 &)[1, 2], 1 + 2, 3},
>  {(#1 + #2 &)[1, 3], 1 + 3, 4},
>  {(#1 + #2 &)[2, 1], 2 + 1, 3},
>  {(#1 + #2 &)[2, 2], 2 + 2, 4},
>  {(#1 + #2 &)[2, 3], 2 + 3, 5},
>  {(#1 + #2 &)[3, 1], 3 + 1, 4},
>  {(#1 + #2 &)[3, 2], 3 + 2, 5},
>  {(#1 + #2 &)[3, 3], 3 + 3, 6},
>  {{2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}}
> ```

Basically you get "free" performance for certain operators, but in general `Outer` is a pairwise operation that does not use vector optimizations.  See Leonid's post on the topic:

- [Fastest way to calculate matrix of pairwise distances](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21861/fastest-way-to-calculate-matrix-of-pairwise-distances/21863#21863)

---

An examination of `Table` will also show that there are hidden optimizations taking place.  Consider this potentially baffling example:

```
Table[i + j, {i, 1, 1000}, {j, 1, 1000}]; // RepeatedTiming

n = 1000;
Table[i + j, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0127, Null}
>
> {0.220, Null}
> ```

I first learned of this from [a post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8709170/618728) and it really shocked me.  But it has a reasonable explanation which is that when `Table` sees explicit numeric ranges it triggers an optimized routine.  When it does not, as in the second case, it allows for the possibility of a changing value of `n` in the `j` iterator by using a slower but more literal algorithm.  Here are two examples where the value of `n` *does* change; try to guess the output of each before you check it yourself:

```
n = 3;
Table[i + j, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n++}]

n = 3;
Table[(n++; i + j), {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
```

Another Stack Overflow post I actually answered before I understood what was going on with `Table`:

- [Using Array and Table Functions in Mathematica. Which is best when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764774/using-array-and-table-functions-in-mathematica-which-is-best-when)

(As usual Leonid gave me a [polite nudge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764774/using-array-and-table-functions-in-mathematica-which-is-best-when#comment6610862_5768033) in the right direction.)

And a more recent question on this site:

- [Why does array packing in Table behave like this?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22277/121)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Wizard. What do you mean by "free" performance?

Comment: @matheorem What I meant is that where the developers saw fit to provide low-level optimizations you get a very nice performance boost without any additional effort like compiling to C.  However the fast performance in such a case *cannot* be taken to mean that the function (like `Outer`) itself is fast.  This has tripped me up a number of times as I tend to think, subconsciously if nothing else, things like "`ListCorrelate` is fast" then I am surprised when I see that my program is slow, only to realize that I used `ListCorrelate` in a non-default way, which is not optimized like the default.

Comment: I understand. Another question, Why `Table` is much faster than `Map` in this case ? Is it general?

Comment: @matheorem I added a few comments on `Table` that I hope you find illuminating.

Comment: Wow, I am shocked too ! Thank you so much for providing such valuable links, I learned a lot. And I find `Array[#1 + #2 &, {1000, 1000}]` is 10 times faster than `Outer[#1 + #2 &, Range[1000], Range[1000]]`, and this is not easily read from the `TraceInternal`, since the trace output are almost the same. It seems that they both works pairwise, right?